# Piping question for garbage disposal installation

Tags: plumbing, garbage-disposal, kitchen-sink

What do I do if the garbage disposal outlet is lower than the wall connection pipe?

Comment: Can you post a photo?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need open up the wall and move the drain down.